# Failed to instantiate [org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.EndpointDefinitionParser$SpringEndpointImpl].No default constructor found

Tags: java, spring, cxf, endpoint

Recently I have to upgrade `CXF 2.7 to CXF 3.1.2` . The spring version we are using is `Spring 4.1.8` .

The error occurs when trying to create EndPointImpl object in the below lines :

```
 EndpointImpl myWSImpl = (EndpointImpl)Boot.getAppContext().getBean("myWebService");
```

Please note that I can not upgrade to `Spring 4.2` yet, so I had to comment out these lines in `context.file`, to use `cxf 3.1` with `Spring 4.1`

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>
```

I have tried to do the following :

```
Bus bus = (Bus)  Boot.getAppContext().getBean(Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID);
Object implementor = Boot.getAppContext().getBean("myWebService");
EndpointImpl myWSImpl = new EndpointImpl(bus, implementor);
```

but I still get the same error and I found the following error in logs:

```
04-Apr-2018 15:18:37.255 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1]
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception
sending context initialized event to listener instance of class
[org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener] 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'myWebService': Instantiation of bean failed;
nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
instantiate
[org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.EndpointDefinitionParser$SpringEndpointImpl]:
No default constructor found; nested exception is
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.EndpointDefinitionParser$SpringEndpointImpl.<init>()
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:759)
    at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:434)
    at
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:630)
    at
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1842)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
Source)     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)   at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)  at
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
instantiate
[org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.EndpointDefinitionParser$SpringEndpointImpl]:
No default constructor found; nested exception is
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.EndpointDefinitionParser$SpringEndpointImpl.<init>()
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:85)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1092)
    ... 26 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.EndpointDefinitionParser$SpringEndpointImpl.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)  at
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)  at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
    ... 27 more
```

What else can I do to remove this error.

Thanks.

Comment: Tried that but still same error . 'myWebService' class is basically a SOAP WebService class.
Also ,  Failed to
instantiate
[org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.EndpointDefinitionParser$SpringEndpointImpl  , I suppose internally when cxf is trying to get a bean for myWebService class , it is trying to instatntialte SpringEndpointImpl  , which doesn't contain any default constructor, hence the error.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing with this problem now, using CXF 3.3.4 and Spring 5.1.16.